# React/Typescript using MUI Cards, translating the card-body above the card-media having a card action causes some issues

Tags: css, material-ui, react-typescript

I am trying to create a MUI Card that will display a photo and when you hover over it, it will display some data from the photo using css. I added a button to a card actions section that opens a dialog to display the image in full. When I click the button in the Card Actions section it will bring up the photo properly, however, when I close the photo it causes the card body to press up the card media section and takes up half the view window area. I am rather new to using MUI and react overall.

Here is the card class

```
const photoContext = useContext(PhotoContext);
```

return (

```
<Card tabIndex={0} className="card">
  <CardMedia className="card-photo" sx={{ height: 140, position:'relative'}} image={props.photo.photo_url} />
  <CardHeader className="card-header" titleTypographyProps={{fontSize:'12pt'}} title={'Salt Lake City'} />
  <CardContent className="card-body">
    <Typography>
      Photo Taken: {props.photo.insert_date}
      <br />
      Photo Taken By: Me
      <br />
      Address: 20 East Broadway Eugene, OR 97401
    </Typography>
    <CardActions sx={{ gap: 0, padding: 0 }} disableSpacing={true}>
      <button className="photo-button" tabIndex={-1} onClick={() => {
        photoContext.photoDialogURL(props.photo.photo_url)
        photoContext.photoDialogOpen();
      }}>View photo</button>
    </CardActions>
  </CardContent>

</Card>
```

Here is the CSS I am using

```
.card {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
overflow: clip;
padding: .5 rem;
gap: .5 rem;
position: relative;
& .card-body{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    transition: translate 300ms ease-in;
    translate: 0 100%; 
    background-color: #242424;
    color: white;
    
}

&:hover,
&:active,
&:focus,
&.active{
    .card-body{
        translate: 0 0;
    }
}
```

}
[image: This is what I see after clicking on the button]